# Import excel font property into php

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am importing an Excel spreadsheet into MySQL using a PHP script.
Some of the rows in the spreadsheet have strike-through font to indicate end of life. I would like to capture this and either ignore those rows or set a flag in my database to indicate its status.
I think PHPExcel can do it, but I don't want to have to re-engineer my script if I can help it.

Is this possible?
Please note, I can import Excel spreadsheet ok. I just don't know how to read a cells font properties.

My connection string is:

```
try {
    $filename='D:\\www\\root\\xl\\DVN2_Equipment_Names.xlsx';
    $excelsql = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};;DriverID=1046;FIL=Excel 12.0;READONLY=TRUE;DBQ=D:\\www\\root\\dvn2\\DVN2_Equipment_Names.xlsx;DefaultDir=D:\\www\\root\\dvn2\\;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;Readonly=True;IMEX=0;");
    $excelsql->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
} catch(PDOException $e) {     
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

My query is:

```
$query = "SELECT F8, `DVN 2 Customer Site Names`,`DVN 2 Customer Chassis Names`,F17,`DVN Engineering - Network Design > DVN`,F22,F2,F4  FROM ['CUST sites$'] where F1 is not null"; 

//Get excel data
try { 
    $stmt = $excelsql->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo $stmt->rowCount(); // 1 
    echo "Table dvntemp Deleted<br>";  
} catch(PDOException $e) {   
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
} 

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Get Excel Data:\n");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $site_code = $row['F8'];  //Node Code
    $site_id = $row['DVN 2 Customer Site Names']; //Site Name
    $site_loc = $row['DVN 2 Customer Chassis Names']; //Chassis Name
    $ip_add = $row['F17'];
    $mcast = $row['DVN Engineering - Network Design > DVN'];
    $sys_loc = $row['F22'];
    $dim1 = $row['F2'];
    $dns1 = $row['F4'];

    if (strtolower ($dim1) == 'yes'){
        $dimetis =1;
    }else{
        $dimetis =0;
    }

    if (strtolower ($dns1) == 'yes'){
        $DNS =1;
    }else{
        $DNS =0;
    }

    # $multicast=$fn->makemulticast($site_loc);
    $multicast=$fn->makemulticast($mcast);


    //generate itam name
    $ASSETIDNEW1=str_replace(':','-',$site_loc);
    $ASSETIDNEW=str_replace('_','-',$ASSETIDNEW1);
    $itamname=strtolower ($ASSETIDNEW);


    $stmt1 = $sql->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO `dvntemp` 
    (
        site_code,
        site_id,
        system_name,
        ip_add,
        mcast, 
        sys_loc,
        systype,
        itamname,
        dimetis,
        DNS
    )
    VALUES 
    (
        :site_code, 
        :site_id, 
        :site_loc, 
        INET_ATON (:ip_add),
        INET_ATON (:mcast),
        :sys_loc, 
        :systype,
        :itamname,
        :dimetis,
        :DNS
    )
    "); 


    $stmt1->execute(array(':site_code' => $site_code, ':site_id' => $site_id, ':site_loc' => $site_loc, ':ip_add' => $ip_add, ':mcast' => $multicast, ':sys_loc' => $sys_loc,':systype' => $systype, ':itamname' => $itamname, ':dimetis' =>$dimetis,':DNS' => $DNS));
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you access an excel file via odbc, you are interested in the data, not how it is formatted. If you need formatting information, then you need sg like phpexcel. Or use a separate column in excel to indicate that an item is closed instead of using character formatting. It would be a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks Shadow, I was hoping I could get away with it. I'll ask the owners of the spreadsheet if they can add a status column, or  a VB script that sets status column based on font property.